# Variable not set in function wih createCollection mongodb module

Tags: node.js, mongodb

---

Hello i have created a  function (see below) to test if collection exist in my mongodb

And function should return a status : "EXIST" or "NOT_EXIST" and value by default is "UNKNOWN"

And after running the js program i got : "UNKNOWN",  variable is not set whereas console.log display information "EXIST"

```
VirtualBox:\~/PROJECT/Docker-Nodejs/internal_modules$ node mongo.js
Debugger attached.
Code running
return variable UNKNOWN
result variable : UNKNOWN
console log : EXIST
```

why variable is not updated ?.

my function => MongoCreationCollection
you can see that i force variable to be NOT_EXIST or EXIST and in console log display good information but variable is not changed under createCollection module

```
function MongoCreationCollection(databasename,name){
    var variable = "UNKNOWN";
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
        const db = client.db(databasename)

        db.createCollection(name, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                //console.log(err);
                if (err.codeName =="NamespaceExists") {
                    variable="EXIST"
                    console.log("console log : "+variable);
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("Collection created! : "+name+"");
                variable="NOT_EXIST"
                console.log("console log : "+variable);
            }
        });
    });
    console.log("return variable "+variable);
    return variable;
};
```

```
var result = MongoCreationCollection(database,"enfants");
console.log("result variable : "+result+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB connections and operations return promises which need time to fulfill if you wish to use the results. You need to write either "async/await" statements or "then()" statements to wait for each step to complete before moving to the next.

```
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })

async function MongoCreationCollection(databasename, collectionName) {
  var variable = "UNKNOWN";
  try {
    const database = client.db(databasename)

    await database.createCollection(collectionName)
    variable = "NOT_EXIST"
    console.log(`Collection created: ${collectionName}`)
    console.log("console log: " + variable);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.codeName == "NamespaceExists") {
      variable = "EXIST"
      console.log("console log: " + variable);
    }
  } finally {
    await client.close()
    console.log("return variable: " + variable);
    return variable
  }
}

const result = await MongoCreationCollection(database, "enfants")
console.log("result variable: " + result)
```

I tested this code against my own MongoDB database and it worked every time. Producing the following responses

```
Collection created: enfants
console log: NOT_EXIST
return variable: NOT_EXIST
result variable: NOT_EXIST
```

and then...

```
console log: EXIST
return variable: EXIST
result variable: EXIST
```

I also verified that the collection was actually created in the database.